# Component imported in another component is not showing - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hi just started to learn basics of React and have problem with rendering my component in another component.

`<Header>` component imported in index.js is not showing.

**Index.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                           <Header />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('container'));
```

I have this error:
`Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

**Header.js** component also:

```
import React from "react";

export class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open up the URL it says:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Which means:

- you forgot to import `Header` in a file
- you import it incorrect way,
- `Header` is not exported in a file
- all of the above

**After your edit:**

You need to fix export (like I wrote above) to:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
```

you miss the `default`.

Comment: Yes, when I added `export default Header;` in the end it worked just fine. Why is it not working like `export class Header extends React.Component{}` ?

Comment: @user9347049 that's great :) If I helped feel free to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: So it needs to be also in top. Okay, than you for your answer!

Comment: you can use **export default class** also. but if you are using class name as `export default class Header extends React.Component {`  Then you should import your class like `import {Header} from './components/Header';` . Because when you mention **default** , only the class is exported and no need to use {} in importing. If not mentioning **default** then you are about to export multiple functionalities, so mention {} in import. Hope it clarified your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export default class Header extends React.Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

Use the `default` keyword while exporting the Header.js

it'll start working fine :)